# Converting non-English manual pages to PDF/PostScript

Tags: fonts, pdf, man, groff, postscript

I'm trying to convert manual pages containing either Japanese or Russian characters to the PDF/PostScript formats. I'm doing it with the following commands.

`man -Tpdf /usr/share/man/ja/man1/vim.1.gz > vim-ja.pdf`

`man -t /usr/share/man/ja/man1/vim.1.gz > vim-ja.ps`

`man -Tpdf /usr/share/man/ru.UTF-8/man1/vim.1.gz > vim-ru.pdf`

`man -t /usr/share/man/ru.UTF-8/man1/vim.1.gz > vim-ru.ps`

These commands return a bunch of warnings of the following form.

`troff: <standard input>:2: warning: can't find special character 'u540D'`

The resulting documents do not contain characters of the specified languages. Only English characters appear in the documents.

How to properly convert manual pages containing non-English characters to PDF/PostScript?

Comment: Does this also happen if you add `-E utf8` after `-Tpdf `? Or `-R utf8`?

Comment: @MarcusMüller The `man -Tpdf -E utf8 input.1.gz > output.pdf` command returns a bunch of warnings of the following form: `troff: <standard input>:39: warning [p 1, 3.8i]: cannot adjust line`.  The resulting document is not a document of the PDF format (just a plain text document).

Comment: @MarcusMüller The `man -Tpdf -R utf8 intput.1.gz > output.pdf` doesn't return any warnings. But the resulting document is also not a PDF document. It's a plain manual page.

Comment: ah then I'm out of ideas (unless that newly generated plain manual page can be sensibly converted)

Answer (score 1):

It probably uses `gropdf` from `groff`.

My manpage says:

> Note that gropdf is currently only able to display the first 256
> glyphs in any font.  This restriction will be lifted in a later
> version.

That seems to be the reason.

Edit: It might also be your local font doesn't have these glyphs.